# Android - Is it possible to change a property specifically for each ListPreference entry?

Tags: android, xml

I have an ordinary Android ListPreference defined in my code -

```
<ListPreference
        android:title="Font"
        android:summary="Choose the font of the reader"
        android:key="fontList"
        android:entries="@array/fonts"
        android:entryValues="@array/fontValues">

    </ListPreference>
```

It gives a list of a couple of different font types that the user can pick from, nothing special. What I wondering is, is there a way to set each list item's font to the font that it displays? This would be a nice feature as it would allow the user to see what they have to pick from before having to test it out.

I can't see any obvious way of doing it, or at least a way that wouldn't destroy the nice default UI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to extend the ListPreference class and implement your own preference.  From memory I think you need to override the onCreateDialogView, onBindDialogView, onSetInitialValue and onDialogClosed methods.  Best place to look is at [the List Preference page on developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html)

Answer (score 0):

like he said for fonts u will need custom one. But what I found that there are alot of different default android:theme="@android:style/Theme....."
try the once that are available ... there are 9-10 of them.
maybe u will get somewhat closer to what u need that extending your own custom UI.